# Maximum Pair Product strange results

Tags: c++

I have been trying to learn C++ from a C# background, and I am running in to a very weird mistake in my Maximum Pair Product method.

The method works as expected with small numbers. For products of large numbers it produces a strange rounding and outputs the incorrect output.

```
int64_t Testing::MaximumPairProductFast(const std::vector<int>& numbers)
{ 

    int64_t largestIntA = 0;

    int64_t largestIntB = 0;

    for (int  i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        // find first largest number
        if (numbers[i] > largestIntA) largestIntA =  numbers[i];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        //find second largest number
        if (numbers[i] > largestIntB && numbers[i]!= largestIntA) largestIntB = numbers[i];
    }

    return  largestIntA * largestIntB;


}
```

The main program

```
int main()
{

    Testing ch;

    std::vector<int> test{ 100000,90000 };  

    int result= ch.MaximumPairProductFast(test);

    std::cout << result << "\n";

}
```

The output of the computation will be `410065408` **instead of** `9000000000` which is the correct answer

The weird thing is when I try to print this:

```
std::cout << (int64_t) 100000 * 90000 << "\n";
```

It does give the correct result `9000000000`.

But if I don't cast it to `int64_t` :

```
std::cout <<  100000 * 90000 << "\n";
```

The result is `410065408`, which is exactly the output from my method even though I have ensured to return an `int64_t` type.

I have also tried this, but the outcome is the same:

```
int64_t Test::MaximumPairProductFast(const std::vector<int>& numbers)
{ 

    int64_t largestIntA = 0;

    int64_t largestIntB = 0;

    for (int  i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        // find first largest number
        if ((int64_t) numbers[i] > largestIntA) largestIntA = (int64_t) numbers[i];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        //find second largest number
        if ((int64_t) numbers[i] > largestIntB && (int64_t) numbers[i]!= largestIntA) largestIntB = (int64_t) numbers[i];
    }


    return  largestIntA * largestIntB;

}
```

Am I missing an obvious detail?

Answer (score 2):

You are truncating your result from a `int64_t` to an `int`.  On a typical system these days, you'll truncate a 64 bit integer and store it in a 32 bit value.

If you compile with the warning level increased, the compiler will tell you about this problem.

The solution is to declare `result` with the proper type:

```
int64_t result = ch.MaximumPairProductFast(test);
```

Or, just let the compiler use the correct type with `auto`:

```
auto result = ch.MaximumPairProductFast(test);
```

In your second example, the constants `100000` and `90000` are integers, so the multiplication of them will be done as integers.  When you case one of the values to `int64_t`, the multiplication will be done with 64 bit ints.  This can also be expressed with `100000LL`.

Answer (score 1):

On your system `int` is a 32-bit integer. `int64_t` is 64-bit integer. The problem in your code is you are multiplying two 32-bit ints so you're getting a 32-bit int result. Your answer is overflowing. When you explicitly cast it to int64_t, the operands are now 64-bit ints and you're getting a 64-bit int result which can hold the large value and not overflow.

I'll suggest you either:

1. use `std::vector<int64_t>` instead of `std::vector<int>`
2. If you're worried about space, do as you did, explicitely cast it to 64-bit int and then multiply

Comment: AAgh! yes I missed that `result` was an `int` and not an `int64_t` !! no wonder it was casting the result to a 32-bit number.

Comment: I left `std::vector<int>` would that be ok? it still outputs the correct result.

Comment: @theWiseBro: The problem is not the type in the vector. It is also not the multiplication, which is done in `int64_t`. It is the wrong type on `result` which narrows the result.

Comment: @walnut yeah, I am aware of that. I think I should just delete this post lol... but I will just leave it! ...

Comment: @walnut yes I never said vector type was the problem. I was just giving a solution for his code. The first two points are solutions for his code. The para below the points is what the problem is. Hmm, perhaps I should have first put the problem in his code first and then the solutions, I did the reverse.

Comment: @walnut swapped the two parts. Looks clearer now imo.